# Domain registration

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain

Hello everybody Im new in domains and servers and need some advices.

Hope i will get it here

So i have IBM server with one IP address as i know domain needs dns name servers to forward domain to current ip Address. Today i registered domain NGG-L.com here i my Web Page 46.49.70.30. How i can connect NGG-L.com to 46.49.70.30? Maybe im asking very stupid question but please help me.

I tried to use free dns servers like opendns.com. I have registered on opendns.com configured my server and when i inputed OpenDNS.com`s name servers (208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220) on http://www.maddogdomains.com/

> `set nameservers`

form and i got Invalid TLD.

Please advice me something how i can configure my domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service provided by maddogdomains when registering a domain name includes hosting that domain name.  In other words, in addition to reserving the domain for you, they all provide the service that defines what IP address DNS entries for your domain resolve to.

Unless you particularly want to use a different domain name host, you can use their service, you just need to find the appropriate part of the control panel.  The name servers part should be left as it is currently, with the nameservers for your domain defined as ns23 and ns24.domaincontrol.com

All you need to do is find the section of the control panel that lets you edit your DNS zone (or DNS records).

You'll see an entry in there saying something like:

```
NGG-L.com.              3600    IN      A       68.178.232.99
```

You need to change the IP address at the end to  46.49.70.30

The TTL is an hour, so within an hour, NGG-L.com will resolve to your servers IP address.

Comment: @user525717 DNS has propagated now, and your server is correctly resolved.

Comment: yesss you are the best :)